# SQL query to shuffle columns

Tags: sql, teradata

I've got tables which contains column of roll number, subject name and marks of different subjects.

There are total 25 subjects like Geology, Math, Physics, Biology etc. They are present in database in shuffled for like somewhere Math is in third column and its marks in 4th column, and somewhere it is in 13th column with marks in 14th column. Marks are always adjacent to their own subject.

Is there any SQL query which could arrange all these subjects?

Like all the Biology subjects will be in first column while its marks in next 2nd column.

The query should search all the Biology subjects in the table and place it in first column while replacing that column from where Biology was found, the subject name of the subject which was in first column along with its marks.

Eg. If for roll number 100, if at first row there is math and at 2nd there is math's marks, and biology is at 5th column and its marks at 6th column, it should swap column 1 with 5 and column 2 with 6.

Comment: Prepare http://sqlfiddle.com with sample data and desired output. I will be much easier to provide accurate answer.

Comment: I am working in teradata, which supports sql querry

Comment: You shouldn't store data like that so wanting them all back in columns is not a good idea.

Comment: I know. But is there any way? @JakubKania

Comment: @zohaibkhan There is always a way, but please rather choose a way that will get you out of this messy schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways this can be done. The first way is to `UNION ALL` the columns:

```
SELECT id, col1 AS subject, col2 AS mark FROM table
UNION ALL
SELECT id, col3, col4 FROM table
UNION ALL
...
```

This way you can create a query you should use to transform it into a id, subject, mark table. If you really don't want that then you can use it to recreate your table:

```
WITH subjects AS(
SELECT id, col1 AS subject, col2 AS mark FROM tbl
UNION ALL
SELECT id, col3, col4 FROM tbl
UNION ALL
...
)
SELECT id, bio.subject, bio.mark, math.subject, math.mark ...
FROM subjects AS bio
JOIN subject AS math ON bio.id=math.id
JOIN subject AS ...
WHERE bio.subject = 'biology' and math.subject = 'math' and ...
```

The other (and probably much more efficient way will be to use `CASE` statement

```
SELECT CASE WHEN col1 = 'biology' THEN col2
       ELSE WHEN col3 = 'biology' THEN col4
       ELSE ...
       AS biology,
       CASE WHEN col1 = 'math' ...
FROM tbl
```